# Finding the derivative of $ \dfrac{1}{z}$ by using the definition of derivative

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

I'm trying to find the derivative of $ f(z) =  \dfrac{1}{z}$ by using the definition:

$$\lim_{ h\to 0}\frac{f(z+h) - f(z)}{h} $$

I have already solved it with the help of the Cauchy-Riemann equations, so i know what the answer is, but i want to solve it with the definition aswell. However, while trying to solve it i arrive at:

$$\lim_{ h\to 0}\frac{|z|^2*(\overline {z+h}) - |z+h|^2*\overline {z}}{h*|z+h|^2*|z|^2} $$

which seems wrong, since i can't continue from there.

Comment: This shouldn't require using anything about complex numbers in particular (as opposed to, say, real numbers).

Comment: @user76284 i was thinking that since for example $ \dfrac{1}{z+h} $ has a complex denominator, that i have to multiply both the denominator and numerator with its conjugate. Is there a reason why i don't do it, since i've learned that if you have a complex denominator, the way to go is to multiply with its conjugate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is quite easy actually:
$$ \frac{ f(z+h) - f(z) } {h}
= \frac { 1/(z+h) - 1/z }{h}
= \frac{ z - (z+h) }{z(z+h)h }
= \frac{ -h} {z(z+h)h}
=-\frac{1}{z(z+h)} \xrightarrow{h\to0} -\frac{1}{z^2}$$

Comment: This might be a stupid question, but since, for example, the denominator in $ \dfrac{1}{z+h}$ is a complex number, don't i have to multiply both the denominator and numerator with its conjugate?

Comment: @Fosofof No. This is just a trick to get such a fraction into a form where the denominator is real, but that is not at all nescessary for mathematical reasons, it is only nescessary if we want to express the resulting number in the form of $A+Bi$.

Basically $\mathbb C$ is a field, so unless $z+h=0$ the expression $1/(z+h)$ makes total sense.